# How to concatinate random generated string in Kubernetes secret yaml

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have MongoDB and the backend pod needed to be running in the cluster. I want to generate the random password for Mongodb and use it as a connection string in my backend. Here is what my K8s secret looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mongo-secrets
type: Opaque
data:
  MONGO_ROOT_USER: "root"
  MONGO_ROOT_PASS: $(head -c 24 /dev/random | base64)
  MONGO_DSN: 'mongodb://root:%{MONGO_ROOT_PASS}@localhost:27017/db'
```

`MONGO_ROOT_USER, MONGO_ROOT_PASS` is for MongoDB pod which is working fine. `MONGO_DSN` is for the backend pod which will connect to MongoDB.

As you can see `MONGO_DSN` value wouldn't work like that. I have tried with anchor reference also but the anchor in YAML doesn't support concatenation.

How to achieve this? My requirement is to generate the random password in K8s secret and use it again in the backend pod. Or this is not possible at all.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Plain Kubernetes YAML can't run shell commands.  Environment-variable substitution is only possible at one very specific point (inside the `env:` block of a Pod spec).  You can't really build this as you describe.

Normally I'd recommend creating YAML files, checking them into source control, and using `kubectl apply -f` to install things in the cluster.  If you need to generate an actually-random password, though, you may need [`kubectl create secret` at the command line](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configmap-secret/managing-secret-using-kubectl/#create-a-secret)

```bash
kubectl create secret generic mongo-secrets \
  --from-literal=MONGODB_ROOT_PASS=$(head -c 24 /dev/random | base64)
```

Note that your local shell runs the subcommand before passing the argument to `kubectl` (try putting `echo` at the very start of the line to see the result of shell processing); Kubernetes still doesn't know anything about the subcommand.

The `MONGO_DSN` syntax isn't especially sensitive and you need to assemble it at the point where you use it.  You can [use `$(VARIABLE_NAME)` syntax](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-interdependent-environment-variables/) to include other variables specifically inside an `env:` block in a Pod spec (usually embedded in a Deployment, Job, or StatefulSet object).

```yaml
env:
  - name: MONGODB_ROOT_USER  # inlined for simplicity, could also be
    value: root              # embedded in the Secret
  - name: MONGODB_ROOT_PASS
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: mongodb-secrets
        key: MONGODB_ROOT_PASS
  - name: MONGO_DSN
    value: mongodb://$(MONGODB_ROOT_USER):$(MONGODB_ROOT_PASS)@localhost:27017/db
```

Comment: Yes i might probably not create mongoDSN key but the things is i am not allowed to touch the deployment files of any of these. deployment is configured to take data from either secret key or plain dsn fields.